Saving date objects in MongoDb from Scala.js
I have a serverless application written in Scala.js that is writing to a MongoDb database. We wrote our own custom integration with the Node.js mongodb driver. Everything is working well except for date objects. I am attempting to find a way to serialize my objects so that mongo can interpret them as a date object, rather than a string.
Without getting to much in detail, the code uses Circe Encoders to serialize the objects to Json. Here is the encoder I am using for the date object:
  implicit val dateEncoder: Encoder[Date] = Encoder.encodeJson.contramap[Date] {
    date =>
      Json.obj(
        "$date" -> Json.fromString(date.toISOString())
      )
  }

The Circe Json then gets converted to Scala.js Json before interacting with the Node.js driver.
In the encoder above, I am attempting to replicate the bson format of date objects that I see in this documentation. Conceptually, it is working correctly, as I see the object is being saved with this value:
{
    "_id" : "test-id",
    "profile" : {
        "IndividualProfile" : {
            "username" : "test.test@test.com",
            "dateCreated" : {
                "$date" : "2024-06-17T15:50:12.059Z"
            },
            "dateUpdated" : {
                "$date" : "2024-06-17T15:50:12.059Z"
            }
        }
    }
}

You can see the dateCreated and dateUpdated objects in the result, and they appear to have the json formatted as intended, but mongo is not interpreting the field as a date object: it’s just an object with a nested string field.
I get this is probably a nice use case, but I was curious if anyone had an idea what I might be missing here?

Are you sure? Maybe it is just the way how it is displayed by your client. Did you try to select the data with a different tool, e.g. mongosh?

I have no clue about Scala.js, however Json.obj looks to me as a function which creates a JSON-Object rather than a Date Perhaps it would be simple date => new Date(Json.fromString(date.toISOString())) or similar. But it would be pointless anyway, because you convert a Date into a string and then back again into a Date. Try even simpler date => date, there is no reason the convert between string and Date forth and back.

In case you want to verify the type of a field in a document in a collection, you can use the $type (aggregation operator) and run a query from MongoDB shell. The result should show as date type (or otherwise).

It was definitely saving it as an object with a nested string field. I use Studio3T, and it gives type information on all the fields.

However, I was able to solve this whole formatting problem by manually invoking bson's EJSON serialize and deserialize functions. So effectively, I am building out the correct structure, serializing it into bson, and then saving that. It now shows up in MongoDb as a date object, so I'm satisfied
